# Arrays in PL/SQL function as return type returning ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: arrays, database, oracle, plsql, sql-like

Have been working on a problem to substitute words in a string based on replacing words that appear in synonym and word-substitution lists. A string could generate more than one string depending on the substitutions. The idea is to get the possible substitution of a string as a function that can be used in a SQL query. However, I am getting the error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error`.Let me go over the previous problem.

Have a table for word substitutions such as:

```
WORD        SUBS_LIST
MOUNTAIN    MOUNTAIN, MOUNT, MT, MTN
VIEW        VIEW, VU
FORMULA     FORMULA, 4MULA, FOURMULA
```

Additionally, I have synonym table as follows:

```
WORD            SYN_LIST
EDUCATION       SCHOOL, UNIVERSITY, COLLEGE, TRAINING
FOOD            SYN, BAR, BISTRO, BREAKFAST, BUFFET, CABARET, CAFE, CANTINA, CAPPUCCINO,    ...,
STORE           SYN, CONVENIENCE, FOOD, GROCER, GROCERY,...,
REFRIGERATION   SYN, APPLIANCE, COLDSTORAGE, FOODLOCKER, FREEZE, FRIDGE, ICE, REFRIGERATION
```

If I have a string such as `MOUNT VU SYN GROWERS` the function should return an array of three strings  which are generated for all the possible replacements:

```
MOUNTAIN VIEW STORE GROWERS
MOUNTAIN VIEW FOOD GROWERS
MOUNTAIN VIEW REFRIGERATION GROWERS
```

Then, the function should be called by a query to replace synonyms and substitutions in the following ways:

```
select replace_synonyms('MOUNT VU SYN GROWERS') from dual;

SELECT name, replace_synonyms(name) corrected_name
FROM   institutions
WHERE  replace_synonyms(name) LIKE replace_synonyms('MOUNT VU SYN GROWERS')
```

To approach this problem a function was created to replace a string and provide the possible substutions. Over there I am having problems when assigning the values to the array:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.REPLACE_SYNONYMS", line 35
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.REPLACE_SYNONYMS", line 35

35:  array(v_idx):= regexp_replace(
                  p_text, '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || i.text || '($|[^a-z0-9])', 
                  '\1' || i.word || '\2', 1, 0,  'i');
```

Which correspond to the following values:

```
array(2):= regexp_replace(
                  'MOUNTAIN VIEW SYN GROWERS', '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || 'SYN' || '($|[^a-z0-9])', 
                  '\1' || 'STORE' || '\2', 1, 0,  'i');
```

Please find the [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2cab7820a7538f4d22a090acf0658c7) for specific details and exact case.

How can I get the array returned to be used in the SQL query? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve], not just line 35.  thanks

Comment: Please read carefully, It is in the question (I shared not only the function, but also the setup).

Answer (score 0):

The error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error` turned out to be a error related to the size in the array. Then increasing the value of varray fixed the problem:

```
create type array_t is varray(100) of varchar2(4000);
/
```